Why is Lie algebra $[L_{\lambda}, L_{\mu}]$ contained in $L_{\lambda+\mu}$
This is for the 2nd part of question 9.8 in the book "Introduction to Lie Algebras" by Karin Erdmann and Mark J. Wildon.
A generalized eigenspace of derivation $\delta$ is defined as as $L_\lambda = \{x \in L: (\delta - \lambda 1_L)^m x = 0 for \space some \space m \geq 1\}$,
and I was able to prove that if $\lambda,\mu \in \textbf{C}$ and $x, y \in \textbf{L}$, then $(\delta - (\lambda + \mu)1_L)^n[x,y] = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}[(\delta - \lambda 1_L)^kx, (\delta - \mu 1_L)^{n-k}y]$.
The 2nd part of question asks that if the primary decomposition of $\textbf{L}$ with respect to derivation $\delta$ is $L = \bigoplus_\lambda \textbf{L}_\lambda$, then $[L_\lambda, L_\mu] \subseteq L_{\lambda + \mu}$.
What is puzzling to me is that if the primary decomposition of L with respect to $\delta$ is $L = \bigoplus_\lambda \textbf{L}_\lambda$, why would there garanteed to exist another eigenvalue $\lambda+\mu$ with generalized eigenspace $\textbf{L}_{\lambda+\mu}$, such that $[L_\lambda, L_\mu] \subseteq L_{\lambda + \mu}$?
And based on similar argument, can I say there is another eigen value $2\lambda + \mu$, or $3\lambda + 4\mu$, so on and so forth? Wouldn't that be an infinite sequence?

If $\lambda+\mu$ is not an eigenvalue then $L_{\lambda+\mu}=0$.

Thanks for resolving my confusion fast! I can just accept it if you make the comment answer @DavidA.Craven
